# metaclass __call__ vs baseclass __new__

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

I wonder a bit about the difference between `__new__` of a baseclass vs `__call__` of a metaclass.

Consider this example code:

```
class Metaclass(type):
  def __call__(cls, *args):
    print("Metaclass.__call__", cls, args)
    obj = type.__call__(cls, *args)
    return obj  # cls.__init__ was already called


class DemoWithMetaclass(metaclass=Metaclass):
  def __init__(self, x):
    print("DemoWithMetaclass.__init__", x)
    self.x = x


class Baseclass(object):
  def __new__(cls, *args):
    print("Baseclass.__new__", cls, args)
    obj = super(Baseclass, cls).__new__(cls)
    return obj  # cls.__init__ not yet called


class DemoWithBaseclass(Baseclass):
  def __init__(self, x):
    print("DemoWithBaseclass.__init__", x)
    self.x = x


demo1 = DemoWithMetaclass(1)
print("got:", demo1, demo1.x)

demo2 = DemoWithBaseclass(2)
print("got:", demo2, demo2.x)
```

The output would be:

```
Metaclass.__call__ <class '__main__.DemoWithMetaclass'> (1,)
DemoWithMetaclass.__init__ 1
got: <__main__.DemoWithMetaclass object at 0x103b2cb90> 1
Baseclass.__new__ <class '__main__.DemoWithBaseclass'> (2,)
DemoWithBaseclass.__init__ 2
got: <__main__.DemoWithBaseclass object at 0x103b34e10> 2
```

One difference is that via a baseclass `__new__`, you cannot translate the arguments or sth like that.
Depending on the use case, this might be a minor or non-relevant difference.
A metaclass provides further meta programming via its `__new__` or `__prepare__`.

Both could be used to implement singletons.
When you use a baseclass `__new__` to return an existing instance in certain cases, `__init__` will be called on the already existing instance where `__init__` was already called before, so you might need to take some extra care about that.

Are there other differences? Or reasons to use a metaclass over just a baseclass, assuming we don't need any of the other meta programming functionality?